# Regex pattern for 2 or more alphabetic characters used in a group 2 or more times in a string vba

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am in need of a regex pattern, let's say i want the pattern to be any 2 or more alphabetic characters used in a group (eg: "ab"/"abb"/"abbb"/), consecutively 3 or more times in a string(eg:"ababab"/"abbabbabb"/"abbbabbbabbb"), I have this function that finds if a character is used 3 times or more consecutively in a string that i want to adapt.

```
Function TripleChars(S As String) As Boolean
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([a-z])\1\1"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    TripleChars = .test(S)
End With
End Function
```

I'm new af to regex i tried a free pattern generator and got to:

```
([a-z]([a-z])([a-z])?([a-z])?)\1\1\1?\1?
```

but i feel it's pretty unprofessional/manual having to add same statements until forever if the number gets higher...

Comment: Maybe [`([a-z]{2,})\1\1`](https://regex101.com/r/oCX4uV/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, yes it works for the first part of the grouping of characters, but on the second part it stops after 3 groups of characters, wanting it to go as long as the groups exists(3+). I think i'll just add 10 occurances as it's highly peculiar to exist more.

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite get what your expected results are.

Comment: Please update the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was saying as for pattern, taking characters and figuring the pattern for groups it works eg:(ab, aab, aaab, abab, aabb, aaabbb) but for the occurrences of these groups it doesn't. It stops at 3 occurrences, when I want it to go infinitely. Currently using ([a-z]{2,})\1\1\1?\1?\1?\1? for 7 occurrences.

Comment: Try `([a-z]{2,})\1{7}` for exact 7 repetitions. `([a-z]{2,})\1{3}` for 3 repetitions. `([a-z]{2,})\1{3,}` for 3 or more repetitions. Does this work now as you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes i just saw that in front of me now, i think that will work, i'll just put 100 there and it should safe :D Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
([a-z]{2,})\1{1,100}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oCX4uV/2)

Here,

- `([a-z]{2,})` - Group 1 capturing 2 or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `\1{1,100}` - 1 to 100 consecutive occurrences of the same letter as captured in Group 1. The `\1` is a [**numbered backreference**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) that accesses the corresponding group value and lets you match exactly the same text (not pattern!).

Note that if you need to match exactly 7, or *n* occurrences, use `{7}` [**limiting quantifier**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit).